# Проставлять ID пока последовательность непрерывна

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Есть Таблица с данными вот такого вида:

```
ID Type    
1  0    
2  1    
3  1    
4  0    
5  1
```

Я хочу заджойнить таблицу на себя по ID+1 и для всех подряд идущих записей с типом 1 предыдущий ID от записи с Type 0.

```
ID Type    
1  0    
1  1    
1  1    
4  0    
4  1
```

Т.е в итоге я хочу получить результат вот такого вида.

Можно ли это сделать без циклов? Малину портит, что мне нужно на N записей вперед все проставлять, а не на 1...

Comment: Что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Если текущая ID имеет TYPE=0, а N последующих ID имеют непрерывную последовательность из Type=1, то разносим на них ID, которая имела перед этим TYPE=0.

Answer (score 4):

Необходимый вам результат получен в колонке [Lag_val].

```
CREATE TABLE #TempEx ([Id] int, [Type] int)

INSERT #TempEx
VALUES    
(1,0),    
(2,1),    
(3,1),   
(4,0),    
(5,1);

SELECT [Id],
CASE 
WHEN [Type]=0 
THEN [Id] 
WHEN [Type]=1 and lag([Type]) over(order by [Id],[Type]) != 0
THEN lag([Id],2) over(order by [Id],[Type])
ELSE lag([Id]) over(order by [Id],[Type]) end [Lag_val],
[Type] FROM #TempEx 

DROP TABLE #TempEx
```

Подробнее о функции [LAG](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**UPD**: для версии до 2012 используйте для поиска предыдущего значения вложенный SELECT

```
SELECT [Id],
CASE 
WHEN [Type]=0 
THEN [Id] 
ELSE (SELECT max([Id]) FROM #TempEx t2 WHERE t2.Type = 0 AND  t2.Id<t1.Id) 
end [Lag_val],
[Type] FROM #TempEx t1
```

Comment: Ну с LAG'ом любой может. Однако, я просил ответ в контексте 2008.

Comment: вам написать SELECTы в броке CASE ?)

Comment: Да. Давайте. А то что-то не догоняю для произвольной длинны последоватльности это делать.

Comment: @iluxa1810 как-то так.

Comment: CTE просто для красоты? Что-то не вижу его использования. Обычно через него рекурсию делают.

Comment: @iluxa1810 да, можно и без него, поправил.